# Dynamically Implementing Interface Java

Tags: java, reflection, proxy-classes

So I'm trying to create a little Util that lets me dynamically implement an interface in Java. What I mean by that is, I would like to take an object and forcibly upcast it to another object. Obviously, that's not possible unless all the required methods are present. This is what I have working right now:

```
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T become(T implementation, Object target) {
        Class<?>[] interfaces;
        if (implementation.getClass().isInterface())
            interfaces = new Class<?>[]{implementation.getClass()};
        else
            interfaces = implementation.getClass().getInterfaces();

        return (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(implementation.getClass().getClassLoader(), interfaces, (proxy, method, args) -> {
            method.setAccessible(true);
            for (Method declaredMethod : implementation.getClass().getDeclaredMethods())
                if (method.getName().equals(declaredMethod.getName()) && Arrays.equals(method.getParameterTypes(), declaredMethod.getParameterTypes()))
                    return method.invoke(implementation, args);
            return method.invoke(target, args);
        });
    }
```

While it works just fine, it has one huge flaw. Once you start using more advanced interfaces and start having cases like this the problems start.

```
IFaceA extends IFaceB
IFaceC extends IFaceB, IFaceD
ClassA implements IFaceA

become(new ClassA(), new IFaceC(){
//billions of methods
});
```

in a case like this, you really want to just implement the methods declared in `IFaceD` but you are forced to implement methods from `IFaceB`, and `IFaceD`. If it was possible to sort of trick the ide/compiler into thinking the instance of new `IFaceC` was actually an instance of a class that extends `ClassA` and implements `IFaceC` that would be the desired effect. Although that's probably impossible. Are there any other options? Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to create default interface methods with reflection, but that might be something you want to look into, as you aren't required to override them.

Comment: @JacobG.I am pretty sure that in Java 8 you can put default method implementations in interfaces. On another note, I question why one would need to upcast any sub-class. That sounds like a potential design problem.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I second PM's question. Why are you trying to do this? Perhaps there's a better solution than this distortion of Java's inheritance model.

Comment: I'm attempting to cut down on the number of very similar classes I have.  For example, I have a Holder class that stores data in a specific way. Every holder can be partitioned with a predicate and that returns a PartitionHolder... But every single time I make a new implementation of Holder I need a new implementation of PartitionHolder as well... And often all I need is one extra method...  Eg.  NamedHolder NamedPartitionHolder. I lived with that for a while but it becomes quit a problem over time with more complex implemtations. Even if I can find a better solution I'm also just curious.

Comment: I’m stumbling over the phrase “while it works just fine”. I immediately see several reasons why this can’t “work just fine”. But it’s still unclear what it is supposed to do. You are passing an instance of an actual type, already having implemented all methods, to get back an instance of the same type, not having more accessible methods than before. So what’s the point?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/afcec2dcde63eb37e06ed8a77fe25f15 I managed to figure out something that works quite well. The only real issue is you won't get compile time errors for unimplemented methods. (Obviously).
I don't know why it wouldn't work, it lets you take an instance of a type(even a final type) and add a method to it without any kind of wrapper class. For example: String test = "MyTestString"; Runnable runnable = become(Runnable.class, test, () -> (Runnable)() -> {//do something}. It's rather like JS, but very very dirty.

Comment: Do you want to cast IFaceC into ClassA? That's how it seems like. I think you would have to change how the utility method works

Comment: Oh I get it now.. from your github, I don't think you can pass in non-interface as a type, right?